# Do I need to use Transaction objects with MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, transactions, mono

I need to create a MySQL table and fill it with some data in Mono. I am using the following code to do so:

```
public class TestModel
{
    protected IDbConnection dbcon;

    public TestModel()
    {
        string connectionString = "Server=localhost;"
                                + "Database=cikdata;"
                                + "User ID=root;"
                                + "Password=password;"
                                + "Pooling=false";
        dbcon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        dbcon.Open();

        IDbCommand dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();

        // Create table
        dbcmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE employee (firstname varchar(32), lastname varchar(32))";
        dbcmd.ExecuteScalar();

        // fill this table with some data

        dbcmd.CommandText = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM employee";
        IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(reader.Read()) {
            string FirstName = (string) reader["firstname"];
            string LastName = (string) reader["lastname"];
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + FirstName + " " + LastName);
        }

        // clean up
        reader.Close();
        reader = null;

        dbcmd.Dispose();
        dbcmd = null;
    }

    ~TestModel()
    {
        dbcon.Close();
        dbcon = null;
    }
}
```

I have seen many examples of how to work with MySQL in Mono where `IDbTransaction` is used. The code above works without any of the transaction objects. Do I really need to use the transaction object (and `IDbTransaction.Commit`) in my code?

Sorry for asking such a newbie question. I mainly a C++/PHP developer and I have very little experience with C# and Mono.

Comment: Wrap IDisposable objects in 'using' block, finalizers, as already said, are a bad idea here.

Comment: Thanks, @skolima. I've realized why it is so bad. Also, Do I need to maintain a persistent connection to a database while `TestModel` object is not yet deleted? Maybe it is better to `Open` & `Close` connection on particular database queries / transactions?

Comment: Opening a new connection is a costly operation, so it's usually better to keep it around until you really no longer need it.

Answer (score 3):

You should absolutely NOT enclose that code in a transaction. If you do it you will only confuse yourself or other readers of the code.

The reason in this case is that `CREATE TABLE` causes an [implicit commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/implicit-commit.html) in MySQL so after your first command (`CREATE TABLE`) you will already have commited your transaction and the rest of the commands will happen outside transactions anyway. And rollback or commit won't do anything.

This is how it looks if you try to rollback a `CREATE TABLE`

```
mysql [localhost] {msandbox} (test) > start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql [localhost] {msandbox} (test) > create table transtest(id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.32 sec)

mysql [localhost] {msandbox} (test) > rollback;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql [localhost] {msandbox} (test) > select * from transtest;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Notice how the table is still there...

Comment: So I need to use the transaction object only when inserting some data into the table, right? This way I will be able to rollback the operations within the transaction if something goes bad.

Comment: If you doing two or more insert/update/delete that together for a unit of "all or nothing" then put that inside a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Transaction is a good habit when you are running one operation as set of seperate sql commands.

In this case, it would depend on whether you wanted the create table to be rolled back if the fill code failed.

So you can look at it as the following steps.

```
Start a transaction
Create the table
Insert some data
Commit transaction
```

If you don't have an explicit transaction, then there is an imlicit one, so if you appended some insert statements to the create table statement, and called ExcuteScalar, you'd get the same effect.

Essentially use start transaction / commit transaction when you want nothing to change, if any part of it fails.

Or if you want nothing to be changed by any other user while your 'batch' of operations is being performed.

Comment: Theoretically you're correct. However, in MySQL CREATE TABLE can never be in a transaction so the table will still be created if you do an rollback. I think this is true for ExecuteScalar aswell, since nothing can surround a CREATE TABLE and something else inside the same transaction.

Comment: I wondered about that, but was more concerned with explaining transactions, than getting into details, stayed away from nested as well.

Comment: And MySQL doesn't have nested transactions :)

Comment: Didn't know that, though I can't say I'm surprised, nested transactions greatest utility is in complex stored procedures.